# Stop Mac Calendar auto-adding alerts to events with locations

Tags: macos, calendar, geolocation, alert

In macOS Calendar app, when I create an event, as soon as I add a location, it also automatically adds an alert set to “when I need to leave”.

In app prefs, alerts, for all accounts, I have every dropdown set to “none”, and all checkboxes are unticked.

I do not want any alert to be add automatically ever. How do I disable this?

This does not happen on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off "Time to Leave" notifications in Calendar Settings > Alerts

Comment: That is already done.

Comment: Does it send alerts then, even if it adds that entry to the event? It sounds like its adding the alert so that devices that do want to send that alert can, but it won't actually send the alert if you have Time To Leave off